# Align two li in same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a li item in same line as previous li. For an instance, fourth li and fifth li is on display block. Both of these have 75% width and the sixth one has 25% width. How do I align that six in same position as fourth?

What is happening
[image: What is happening].

What I want.

[image: What I want.]

```css
    #container .default li { float: left;display:inline;} 
    #container .default li:nth-child(7n+1) { background:red; width:50%; height: 100px; }
    #container .default li:nth-child(4n+2),#container .default li:nth-child(6n+3),
    #container .default li:nth-child(7) { background:blue;width:25%; height: 100px; } 
    #container .default li:nth-child(8n+4),
    #container .default li:nth-child(6n+5){width:75%; background:green; height: 50px; }
```

```html
<div id="container"> 
    <ul class="default">
     <li>Item 1</li> <li>Item 2</li> <li>Item 3</li> <li>Item 4</li>
     <li>Item 5</li> <li>Item 6</li> <li>Item 7</li> <li>Item 8</li> 
    <li>Item 9</li> <li>Item 10</li> <li>Item 11</li> <li>Item 12</li> 
    </ul> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A floated item can not go “higher” than a previous floated item on the same line.

Simply *don’t* float item number 6:

```
#container .default li:nth-child(6) { float:none; display:inline-block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0vy4x1uh/7/